# Authentication using SharePoint Web Services

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, sharepoint

I am trying to call GetListItems from an asp.net app.

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential userDefined = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username","password","domain");
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
XmlNode ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");
XmlNode ndViewFields = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");
XmlNode ndQueryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "");
ndQueryOptions.InnerXml = "";
ndViewFields.InnerXml = "";

WebReference.Lists lists = new WebReference.Lists();

lists.Credentials = userDefined;
XmlNode responseNode = lists.GetListItems("My List Name", null, ndQuery, ndViewFields, null, ndQueryOptions, null);
```

I am getting an error:

```
the request failed with http status 401 unauthorized
```

I have searched SO and tried what I have found:

```
WebReference.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

And

```
WebReference.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

And

```
<identity impersonate="true"  userName="mydomain\username" password="password" />
```

with everything I have tried I get the same error message. Would anyone know what I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

if your sharepoint uses browser auth, you'll need to pre-auth

```
svc.PreAuthenticate = true;
svc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/ac38e0da-c828-48b8-aa3f-fb22f30ce581

if its forms auth, or anything other than NTLM, then there's even more mess - though so far, I've had that always respond with 403